# How can i overwrite the error message in bundle? - Wix toolset

Tags: wix, bundle

I want to overwrite the error message according to the error code,as the capture show, the error code is 0x80070001, i want to customize the message to show like "failed to install please go to xxx"

[image]

The **Failure page** section in the theme.xml as follow

```
<Page Name="Failure">
        <Text X="11" Y="80" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.FailureHeader)</Text>
        <Hypertext Name="FailureLogFileLink" X="11" Y="121" Width="-11" Height="42" FontId="3" TabStop="yes" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.FailureHyperlinkLogText)</Hypertext>
        <Hypertext Name="FailureMessageText" X="22" Y="163" Width="-11" Height="51" FontId="3" TabStop="yes" HideWhenDisabled="yes" />
        <Text Name="FailureRestartText" X="-11" Y="-51" Width="400" Height="34" FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="yes" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.FailureRestartText)</Text>
        <Button Name="FailureRestartButton" X="-91" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.FailureRestartButton)</Button>
        <Button Name="FailureCloseButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.FailureCloseButton)</Button>
    </Page>
```

i know that code display the error code and message

```
<Hypertext Name="FailureMessageText" X="22" Y="163" Width="-11" Height="51" FontId="3" TabStop="yes" HideWhenDisabled="yes" />
```

Can i do something to change the message, according to the error code?
By the way, who provide/generate the error code? The windows OS or Wix?

Thanks